# Implementation of Finally Block

Tags: java

In the Code written below although i have not caught the `ArithmeticException`,yet the exception is handled automatically and with `finally` Block, the content of `main()` method is successfully Executed. Whereas if i remove the return statement from finally and make demo as returning void then the program after executing `finally` block throws `MainThread` `Exception`..why is it so?

```
public class FinallyDemo {

  int demo() {        
    try {
      int a=5/0;        
    }        
    finally {
       System.out.println("Finally Executed");
       return 10;   
    }
  }

  public static void main(String s[]) {
    int a=new FinallyDemo().demo();
    System.out.println("Exception Handled");
  }
}
```

Comment: The `finally` block simply swallows your exception.

Comment: Whoa, *way way* too much whitespace...

Comment: caught the exception not cached

Comment: @PravatPanda Caught the exception, not catched ;)

Comment: @AndyPerfect haha :) Perfect one.

Comment: overflow of exception handling emotions ;)

Comment: You may benefit by reading about try-catch-finally at the JLS. Here's the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2

Comment: @PravatPanda emoticons, not emotions.

Answer (score 4):

Because you `return` from the `finally` block, the exception is silently disposed. You should **never** return from a finally block! (Well, almost always never).

From the *Java Language Specification*:

> If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

This also means if you threw a different exception, like an `IllegalStateException`, from the `finally` block, the original exception would also be discarded.

Comment: *Well, almost always never.* So, when should one return from a finally block? :)

Comment: The quote of JLS did not explain the return behaviour, or is a return inside a finally an abrupt completion?

Comment: @AlexWien My understanding is that a `return` from a `finally` is indeed considered "abrupt."

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk Honestly, I can't think of a legitimate reason, but I didn't want to sound overly dogmatic either. There may indeed be a legitimate reason to discard an exception and return some other result. But it is very important to understand the semantics involved in doing so.